# Docker + audio in ubuntu server

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get [ghcr.io/synesthesiam/homeassistant-satellite](https://github.com/synesthesiam/homeassistant-satellite/issues/79) to work on a docker container on my ubuntu server. I got it to work, but it frequently stops workign and give me the following error:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054979' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054981' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054983' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054985' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054987' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054989' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054991' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054993' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054995' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3054997' coro=<ClientWebSocketResponse.send_bytes() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py:153> exception=ConnectionResetError('Cannot write to closing transport')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client_ws.py", line 156, in send_bytes
    await self._writer.send(data, binary=True, compress=compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 688, in send
    await self._send_frame(message, WSMsgType.BINARY, compress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py", line 601, in _send_frame
    raise ConnectionResetError("Cannot write to closing transport")
ConnectionResetError: Cannot write to closing transport
```

In my docker-compose I have the following:

```
    environment:
      - PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/pulseaudio.socket
      - PULSE_COOKIE=/tmp/pulseaudio.cookie
    devices:
      - /dev/snd:/dev/snd
    group_add:
      - audio
```

What am I doing wrong?